# Extractor fan won't start

Tags: electrical, fans

I've moved into a new place and the extractor fan won't work.

The light works via the switch, the same bank of switches with 3 speeds of extractor fan which do nothing.

I've changed the fuse at the switch and the electric tester pen does blink at all points around the fan.

Please see pics

Can anyone provide what step to do next?

Thanks

---

[image: fan unit]
This is the extractorfan unit black lead coming forwards to switches.

---

[image: fan unit sticker]this is the sticker in the chassis of the kitchen Extractor fan

As an update I tested the capacitor and it discharged as expected so it's the motor. New one on the way. So thanks guys much appreciated

Comment: Electrical problem can be only two types: disconnect, there should be connection or short circuit there should be open. Just follow the wires.

Comment: The fan looks like it has a starting capacitor.  They have a habit of going bad.  A multimeter can be used to test it(can google), or a fast test is to take the fan blade cover and spin the blades to get it to start.  be careful, use something soft but stiff enough.  Fingers don't like spinning blades.  Does the motor hum?

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try that tonight. Appreciate your. Input

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the spare parts for your hood: https://www.lamonaspares.co.uk/category/cooking/cooker-hoods/hja2450

It's either the capacitor, the motor, the switch or the connections.  You can narrow it down by opening the little plastic door and determining if power is being applied to the motor when the switch is on.   Be careful, that's 220V in there.

If the switch causes power to appear or not at the motor, then try doing what's suggested in a comment by @crisp659 to determine if it's the capacitor or motor.  Worst case, replace them both .... these parts seem to be priced reasonably.  If the switch does not cause power to appear at the motor, check all the connections and/or replace the switch.  (or something closer to the source of power, but I'm guessing it's not that because the lights work.)